# How to add custom tab in category_from and call a phtml file in it in magento 2?

Tags: magento2

I want to create a custom tab in admin category_from page. After create custom tab i want to call a phtml file.

I have successfully created a custom tab in category_form but when i try to call a block it gives me an error showing

> a:4:{i:0;s:94:"The requested component ("block") is not found. Before using, you must add the implementation.";i:1;s:7167:"#0 /var/www/practice/vendor/magento/module-ui/Model/Manager.php(207): Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\Config\Provider\Component\Definition->getComponentData('block')

This what i have done

category_form.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
<!--    <body>-->
<!--        <referenceBlock name="category_form">
            <block class="Panacea\Custom\Block\Adminhtml\Category\Tab\Custom" name="demo.tab">
                <arguments>
                    <argument name="config" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Custom Design</item>
                        <item name="collapsible" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                        <item name="opened" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                        <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="string">2</item>
                        <item name="canShow" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                        <item name="componentType" xsi:type="string">fieldset</item>
                    </argument>
                </arguments>
            </block>
        </referenceBlock>-->
        <fieldset name="Custom">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Custom Design</item>
                <item name="collapsible" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">100</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
<!--        <field name="custom_attribute">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">1</item>
                    <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">string</item>
                    <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">input</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Custom Attribute</item>
                </item>
            </argument>-->
        <!--</field>-->
<!--        <block class="Panacea\Custom\Block\Adminhtml\Category\Tab\Custom" name="demo.tab">               
            </block>-->
        <!--<block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="CustomTab" template="Panacea_Custom::demo.phtml"></block>-->
         <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="customtab" template="Panacea_Custom::demo.phtml">
                <arguments>
                    <argument name="config" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Custom</item>
                        <item name="collapsible" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                        <item name="opened" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                        <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="string">2</item>
                        <item name="canShow" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                        <item name="componentType" xsi:type="string">fieldset</item>
                    </argument>
                </arguments>
            </block>
    </fieldset>
<!--    <referenceBlock name="content">
            <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="demo.tab">
                <arguments>
                    <argument name="config" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Custom</item>
                        <item name="collapsible" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                        <item name="opened" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                        <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="string">2</item>
                        <item name="canShow" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                        <item name="componentType" xsi:type="string">fieldset</item>
                    </argument>
                </arguments>
            </block>
        </referenceBlock>-->
    <!--</body>-->
</page>
```

and in the comment sessions i have tried to call my block, which i get error all the time.
Need some help

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your **category_form.xml** `Vendor/Module/view/adminhtml/ui_component/category_form.xml` should be

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<form xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
    <fieldset name="custom_fieldset">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Custom Tab</item>
                <item name="collapsible" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">140</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
        <container name="custom_fieldset_container" >
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">200</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
            <htmlContent name="html_content">
                <argument name="block" xsi:type="object">Vendor\Module\Block\Adminhtml\Category\Custom</argument>
            </htmlContent>
        </container>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

Now create `Vendor/Module/Block/Adminhtml/Category/Custom.php`

```php
namespace Vendor\Module\Block\Adminhtml\Category;

class Custom extends \Magento\Backend\Block\Template
{
    /**
     * Block template
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $_template = 'custom.phtml';
}
```

And create template `Vendor/Module/view/adminhtml/templates/custom.phtml`

```html
<h1>Custom Tab Content</h1>
```

Clear cache.

Comment: Got what i wannted

Comment: `protected $_template = 'custom.phtml';` This is ignore by coding standard tool.

Comment: @Sohel Rana how can I disable custom tab for child categories ?